# Display icons instead of words in Visual Studio tool window tabs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, solution-explorer

It's trivial, I know, but yesterday, out of nowhere, Visual Studio 2012 Professional started displaying "Solution Explorer", "Team Explorer - Home", etc. in the tabs instead of nice little icons. Does anyone know how to bring back the icons?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Icons are displayed when the widths of the tabs are too narrow. To get the icons back, either make the pane narrower or dock some more tabs in that pane.

Comment: Is there no way to force the Icons regardless of width? Too much text on my screen as is.

Answer (score 4):

There is an extension that does just that. It was written for VS 2015 but works fine in VS 2017.

[Visual Studio Iconizer for Visual Studio 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlegTarasov.VisualStudioIconizerforVisualStudio2015)

Comment: A version working with VS 2019 is found here: [Visual Studio Iconizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlegTarasov.VisualStudioIconizerforVisualStudio15)

Comment: This should be excepted answer.